# Settting Focus for Rich Text control

Tags: xpages

I can set focus for pretty much any type of control with:

```
var f = dojo.byId('#{id:NotInvitedMsg}');
if (f != null)
   f.focus()
```

But this does not work on rich text controls at least the way I want.  I assume it is setting focus but since the rich text control is made up of multiple components, the edit area is not getting the focus.   Is there anyway to set the focus to the edit area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenNTF finally responded for me and I found this:

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=focus-on-ckeditor-rich-text-field

Works great!

It would have been nice if the poster put a little more effort into documentation.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 try {
 var el = dojo.query('div[id*="yourid"]');
 var node = el[el.length-1];
 setTimeout(function() { node.focus(); }, 500);
//node.focus();
 } catch (e) { }
```